# Force Hazelcast ExecutorService to run on client and not instance

Tags: hazelcast

On each EC2 instance we have a Tomcat process (app) connected to a Hazelcast process (cache).

The Tomcat process connects to its local hazelcast with a `HazelcastClient`.
The Hazelcast process is the one that has all the config (`HazelcastInstance`).

For maps this works great. Now we want to use it for distributed `ExecutorService` as well.

I tried `executeOnAllMembers` but it fired tasks (and exploded on `ClassNotFoundException`) in the cache process.

What's the best way to make sure ExecuteService only targets our app processes and not try to deserialize and run Runnables on the cache process? 
or do I need to make the cache process aware of a custom task serializer?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you look for MemberSelector and Member.setXAttribute as well as IExecutorService::executeOnMembers :)